# Update StreamBuilder stream dynammically using a ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-provider, stream-builder

I have the following build method of a statefull widget. I am trying to test updating a Firebase collection stream dynamically using a ChangeNotifier. The code is the following:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> types = ["pop", "ballad", ''];
    final SongStreamNotifier songStreamNotifier =
        Provider.of<SongStreamNotifier>(context);
    developer.log("Rebuilding Scaffold");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          types.shuffle();
          final songType = types.first;
          songStreamNotifier.getSongsStream(songType);
        },
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: songStreamNotifier.songs,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            developer.log("Rebuilding stream");
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.size,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                    return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('name'));
                  });
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
```

Notifier is called correctly, I can see all log messages on how build is rerun, but the values do not change. The code of the ChangeNotifier is the following:

```dart
class SongStreamNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = Stream.empty();
  final SongService songService = SongService();

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get songs {
    return stream;
  }

  getSongsStream(String type) {
    developer.log('type: $type');
    stream = songService.getSongs(type);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

which is pretty straighforward: `songService.getSongs` filters the songs based on the songType.
I still cannot understand how providers work with updating the state of widgets. How come I see the builder method getting run but the StreamBuilder always fetches the same values?

Answer (score 0):

Found what the issue was. I didn't call `snapshots` on the query but only on the initial collection reference. In my Repository i did this:

```dart
colRef = _db.collection("songs");
if (type != '') {
    colRef.where('kind', isEqualTo: type);
}
return colRef.snapshots()
```

while I should have done

```dart
colRef = _db.collection("songs");
if (type != '') {
    return colRef.where('kind', isEqualTo: type).snapshots();
}
return colRef.snapshots()
```

but I didn't know colRef was immutable.